# Chrome is not starting in Ubuntu 20.04 (ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.)

Tags: google-chrome

I have tried reinstalling chrome; still same issue. I tried deleting google-chrome folder from .cache directory.
I have tried using following command

```
$ google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
$ google-chrome --no-sandbox
$ google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-gpu
```

```
mochan@mochan:~$ google-chrome
mesa: for the --simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --global-isel-abort option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --amdgpu-atomic-optimizations option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --structurizecfg-skip-uniform-regions option: may only occur zero or one times!
[17055:17055:0100/000000.420948:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)


mochan@mochan:~$ google-chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
[16570:16570:0522/205057.285491:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
mochan@mochan:~$ ^C


mochan@mochan:~$ google-chrome --no-sandbox
mesa: for the --simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --global-isel-abort option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --amdgpu-atomic-optimizations option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --structurizecfg-skip-uniform-regions option: may only occur zero or one times!
[16687:16687:0100/000000.992944:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
mochan@mochan:~$ [0522/205209.117905:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(307)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
^C


mochan@mochan:~$ google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-gpu
[16806:16806:0100/000000.957896:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
mochan@mochan:~$ [0522/205344.098949:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(307)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
[16806:16806:0100/000000.101152:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

[These outputs are also in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVHpY.png)

Comment: Please, do not paste screenshots! Please [edit] your question and add the output by copying the text from the terminal screen and pasting it **to the end of your original question** quoted with \`\`\`.

Comment: Okk I did that.. please let me if there is anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem itself got sorted after today's update.