# Cannot start multiple chrome windows from terminal in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, mesa

I have the following script:

```
google-chrome "https://www.google.com"
google-chrome --app=https://listen.tidal.com
google-chrome --app=https://www.notion.so
google-chrome --app=https://outlook.office.com
google-chrome --app=https://teams.microsoft.com
```

When running this I am expecting the following to be started:

1. Normal chrome window on https://www.google.com
2. Tidal as Chrome app
3. Notion as Chrome app
4. Outlook as Chrome app
5. Teams as Chrome app

But It only opens a normal Chrome window on https://www.google.com (only first item).

I noticing the following error in my terminal:

```
mesa: for the --simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --global-isel-abort option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --amdgpu-atomic-optimizations option: may only occur zero or one times!
mesa: for the --structurizecfg-skip-uniform-regions option: may only occur zero or one times!
[620062:620062:0728/172113.887419:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Some observations while debugging:

1. When i first open Chrome via UI, then run script, then it will run correctly and open everything in different windows.
2. When I first run script, close Chrome which opened via script and re-open chrome via UI then i need to select a profile (normally it takes the one from previous session).

I saw this post: [Chrome is not starting in Ubuntu 20.04 (ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339760/chrome-is-not-starting-in-ubuntu-20-04-errorsandbox-linux-cc374-initializes). I have tried to update and reinstall, but did not work. I have not enough rep to ask which version worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add `--new-window` to each command to open them in new window.

Source: `man google-chrome`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. When i try with --new-window on each line, then it opens only the first line ($ google-chrome "https://www.google.com"). Within the terminal I will have the same error as described in original question.